# chain operator function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a function that would obey the following interface in TypeScript 3.2:

```
const s: string = chain(
    () => 123,
    (n: number) => "abc"
    (s: string) => s
);
```

I'm able to do so by declaring multiple-arity functions:

```
function chain2<A, B>(a: () => A, b: (a: A) => B): B {
    return b(a());
}

function chain3<A, B, C>(a: () => A, b: (a: A) => B, c: (b: B) => C): C {
    return c(b(a()));
}

// and so on
```

However, since the [release of Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897), I was wondering if there would be a way to do so with only one function declaration. I've been trying different approaches with no success so far.